# How to color bar charts or blocks with different colors in GNUPLOT V 5.0?

Tags: c++, terminal, gnuplot, trace, ns2

I am plotting a bar chart to compare the results of three different methods. But I am unable to change the color of bar with same method(eg. method A) with the same color, and different method (eg. method B) with same color and third as well.

My data.dat file looks like :

```
0   0.4684
2.0 1.9333
4.0 1.6826

0.5 0.1498
2.5 0.1106
4.5 0.1224

1.0 0.1092
3.0 0.2911
5.0 1.1499
```

I have tried:

```
set size square 1.0, 1.0
set xtics ("label" 0.25, "label2" 1.75, "bar label" 3.25,)
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot 'data.dat' every 2    using 1:2 with boxes ls 1,\
     'data.dat' every 2::1 using 1:2 with boxes ls 2
```

My result:
/home/sudesh/GNUPLOT/Block Chart/Example1.png

Comment: How is your local path to the result useful for this question?

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. But I have solved the problem. If some one could help me with plotting multiple lines(3 lines) with different colors and thick width. For the below .dat file:                                                                                                 1 0.4684  100  0.0050
2 1.9333  91.66  0.0044
3 1.6826  89.65  0.0040